# CoreData Vs FMDB for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I heard using sqlite for long data transition from database is not efficient so I am planning to use FMDB for iphone but want to know if core data is better or not?

What will be an efficient way to do it. tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMDB is just an Objective-C wrapper around sqlite. As such, it does a good job. However, Core Data, when using sqlite as a back-end, may be even more efficient than using sqlite directly, and the framework also provides additional advantages.

Core Data Pro: faster in almost all of the cases, less work to do (Core Data may automatically enforces referential integrity, when setting an entity on one side of a relationships Core Data automatically sets the entity on the other side of the relationships etc).

Core Data Cons: very steep learning curve, especially for advanced features.

Definitely, I recommend switching to Core Data, especially if you did not start your implementation. The time required to learn how to use it will be more than repaid later.